# Where to put included JQuery file

Tags: jquery

I have a customer who want to run a web application on an internal server that does not have access to the Internet, so I cannot include in the header something like the following, which works fine when I have Internet access

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

The (simplified) home page is the following index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
  <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding"/>
  <script src="/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/jquery-3.2.1.min.js""></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      addListener();
    });

    function addListener()
    {
      document.getElementById('browse').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
      document.getElementById('fakeBrowse').addEventListener('click', handleBrowseClick, false);
    }

    function handleBrowseClick()
    {
      var fileinput = document.getElementById("browse");
      fileinput.click();
    }

    function handleFileSelect(event)
    {
      var config = '';
      var file = event.target.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(event) {
        config = event.target.result;
        document.getElementById('config_id').innerHTML = config;
      }
      reader.readAsText(file);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="file" id="browse" name="fileupload" style="display:none"/>
  <input type="button" value="Upload" id="fakeBrowse"/>
  <output id="list"></output>
  <textarea id="config_id"></textarea>
</body>
```

The problem I have is that every time I load the page, I get an error message in the console logs, pointing to this line

```
<script src="/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/jquery-3.2.1.min.js""></script>
```

The error message is the following

```
GET http://localhost:8080/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/jquery-3.2.1.min.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I am sure that file jquery-1.7.1.min.js is at the path I specified, which is the same location than index.html. I also checked that both files have the same ownership and the same permissions

and then it complains about the "$" sign

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at (index):8
```

I also tried using a relative paths like this

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js""></script>
```

or like this

```
<script src="~/jquery-3.2.1.min.js""></script>
```

but no luck.

Anyone can please point me what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT 1**

jquery-1.7.1.min.js is a typo. I meant jquery-3.2.1.min.js

**EDIT 2**

The error was caused by a redundant double-quote at the end of the path. the right path is the following

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: *I am sure that file jquery-1.7.1.min.js is at the path I specified* and all your code using `jquery-3.2.1.min.js` which is not the same

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Sorry, that's a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try to directly access the jquery file by typing the full url in the browser till you get the right url .. you should see the jquery file content .. so first try to access it by using

```
http://localhost:8080/jquery-3.2.1.min.js
```

if not try another and another till you get the right one

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. It helped me find a typo in my path which had a redundant double-quote at the end !

Comment: @rh4games I'm glad it helped .. Have a great day :-)

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you everything, your path is not ok.

Answer (score 0):

/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/... is the absolute file path.

If your running this on a webserver you want to begin after the document root.

If index.html is in the top level of your doc root then the path should just be "jquery-3.2.1.min.js".